# Merge two arrays and return sorted array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting, c#-4.0

---

You are given a function `mergeArrays` which takes in 2 sorted arrays as a parameter. The first array has `M` elements in it, the second one also has `M` elements, but it’s capacity is `2*M`.

The function `mergeArrays` takes both the arrays as parameters along with `M`. You are supposed to merge both the arrays in the second array such that the resulting array is sorted.

**Sample TestCase 0:**

`Input`:

`1st array: {3,5,6,9,12,14,18,20,25,28}`

`2nd array: {30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48 }`

`Output: {3,5,6,9,12,14,18,20,25,28,30,32,34,36, 38,40,42,44,46,48}`

Explanation:
 As stated in the question, the second array contains enough space to accommodate the 1st array. Return the merged sorted array.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me

Comment: Definitely sounds like homework, perhaps you should do them yourself?

Comment: Create the 3d array, merge both arrays into it, then sort the 3d array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution without linq:

```
int[] array1 = new int[] { 3, 5, 6, 9, 12, 14, 18, 20, 25, 28 };
int[] array2 = new int[] { 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48 };

int count1 = array1.Length;
int count2 = array2.Length;
int[] arrayResult = new int[count1 + count2];

int a = 0, b = 0;   // indexes in origin arrays
int i = 0;          // index in result array

// join
while (a < count1 && b < count2)
{
    if (array1[a] <= array2[b])
    {
        // element in first array at current index 'a'
        // is less or equals to element in second array at index 'b'
        arrayResult[i++] = array1[a++];
    }
    else
    {
        arrayResult[i++] = array2[b++];
    }
}

// tail
if (a < count1)
{
    // fill tail from first array
    for (int j = a; j < count1; j++)
    {
        arrayResult[i++] = array1[j];
    }
}
else
{
    // fill tail from second array
    for (int j = b; j < count2; j++)
    {
        arrayResult[i++] = array2[j];
    }
}

// print result
Console.WriteLine("Result is {{ {0} }}", string.Join(",", arrayResult.Select(e => e.ToString())));
```

Result:

```
{ 3,5,6,9,12,14,18,20,25,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48 }
```

Graphical explanation:

[image: Merge]

Comment: You should write an explanation of this code too so the op can include that in their write up

Comment: I dont speak english well to explain code in details, meybe comments help.

Comment: Sorry, it was merely an attempt at sarcasm. Sometimes it is much more useful to the OP not to provide a complete answer, or one such as Dmitry's where it is a working answer that could quite easily be comprehended as pseudo-code - but not very useful. Answering questions such as this one just leads to future poor questions

Comment: I have added image representation that can help.

Comment: this wouldn't work if the two arrays have different sizes, a much simpler solution would be, check if last element in array "a" is greater than the first in array "b", since they are sorted if is smaller, than copy array "a" in the new one, than "b", continuing from where "a" ended, otherwise reverse the order

Answer (score 10):

The solution can be *Linq* query:

```
  int[] first = new int[] { 3, 5, 6, 9, 12, 14, 18, 20, 25, 28 };
  int[] second = new int[] { 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48 };

  int[] result = first
    .Concat(second)
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .ToArray();
```

To test

```
  // 3, 5, 6, 9, 12, 14, 18, 20, 25, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48
  Console.Write(String.Join(", ", result));
```

It works, but it hardly will be *accepted* as a *homework* solution. So I hope you'll elaborate your *own code* using my implementation as a testing reference.

Comment: -1 because this is *not* merge, though it has the same effect. Merging requires traversing the two sorted arrays once and creating a 3rd one, but your algorithm creates a 3rd array by combining the first two sorted arrays and then sorts the third one.